Getting unknown property: craft\events\UserGroupsAssignEvent::user
Event::on(Users::class, Users::EVENT_AFTER_ASSIGN_USER_TO_GROUPS, function(Event $e) {});
When user click on save button, user details and user group was update but user get error Getting unknown property: craft\events\UserGroupsAssignEvent::user
